# If the user logs on successfully, then I want to show the main window, if not, I want to exit the application

Tags: wpf

Stupidly simple question I can't figure out.

I have a WPF application, and I want to display a Logon dialog box first (before the main window shows up).

If the user logs on successfully, then I want to show the main window, if not, I want to exit the application.

How does one do this correctly?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think I figured out what I was trying to do.

1) I needed to set the "StartupUri" in the App.xaml to "Logon.xaml", where Logon.xaml is my logon window.

2) in the LogonButton_Click event handler, I added the following

```
if (blnAuthenticateSuccessful) {
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    App.Current.MainWindow = main;
    this.Close();
    main.Show();
}
```

This seems to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted a new window to appear to allow the user to enter their login information, then I have added some code below. However, creating a true Modal Dialog box is a bit more complicated in WPF so I haven't explained it here. There is information about modal dialog boxes in WPF here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx

From the MainWindow you can open the login window and hide the main window with this:

```
// Code for MainWindow

// Create a new instance of the login window and then show it
LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
loginWindow.Show();

// Hide the MainWindow until later
this.Hide();
```

Then use this on the login page to show the main window again once the user has logged in:

```
// Code for Login window

// This code finds the main window again and shows it
Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
```

Comment: What event would you put this in so that the user did not see the main window first?

Comment: @Sako73 If you take the first bit of code I gave you and put it in the MainWindow constructor that will work nicely. Then when the MainWindow loads it will immediately open the login window, and hide the MainWindow.

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old question but I had a similar problem and I solved it bit differently so just wanted to add that so in future someone might benefit from it.

To solve the problem you can change application shutdown mode to `OnExplicitShutdown` and then call Application.Shutdown(0) whenever you want to. For example:

```
public App()
{
    App.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
}

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // assume code below is for displaying dialog
    if (MessageBox.Show("Continue?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        App.Current.Shutdown(0);
}
```

Here in the constructor, I'm changing application shudown mode and calling Shutdown method when I need to.

Caution: When you change `ShutdownMode` make sure to call `Shutdown` method otherwise your application will be in memory even after main window closes. I've overrided `OnClosed` method in my MainWindow to do that:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
    App.Current.Shutdown(0);
}
```

Comment: Good one! You can even just say `Shutdown();` instead of `App.Current.Shutdown(0);`. The default exit code is 0 anyway.