# C# WPF Application startup error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make something like login window in my application. Of course, I understand that login window shouldn't start the main window - that is why I changed the `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` like this:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         >
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

and I overrided the event in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            bool result = (bool)loginForm .ShowDialog();
            if(result)
            {
                mainWindow.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

That code is working, but it is not good for me because futher I want to push some parameters into the `MainWindow` constructor. So, if I will change code to this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
            bool result = (bool)loginForm .ShowDialog();
            if(result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I am here");
                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                mainWindow.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

If I run this code - I will see my login form, after pressing OK button I will see "I am here" and after that it falls to exception. Help me, please. How to solve that problem? If there is not enought code - I will add it

My login window looks like (Xaml and Xaml.cs):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.LoginForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Hello" Width="480" Height="370">
    <Grid>
    <Button Content="Click Me" Width="100" Height="100" Click="SetDialogResultOK">
    </Grid>
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
</Window>


 public partial class LoginForm : Window
 {
     public LoginForm()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void SetDialogResultOK(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         DialogResult = true;
     }
 }
```

My main window does not contain any interesting. this is a simple window for now

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Nikos, message is The application object is being shut down

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: @Nkosi, okey, I will try to fix it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch WPF windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708992/how-to-switch-wpf-windows)

Comment: @ASh, no, this is not the same way. In the post you shared - main window opens from loginform window. I think this is not correct. Anyway, example of code from there wasnot worked for me

Comment: @Nkosi, I added some more information. Is it enought, how do you think?

Comment: @Pollyflow After reviewing the edits I believe the provided duplicate shows a viable option of how to set the application's main window after logging in. It closely matches your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `ShutdownMode` property to `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown` and then shut down the application when the `MainWindow` is closed:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
    try
    {
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        bool result = (bool)loginForm.ShowDialog();
        if (result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I am here");
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Closed += (ss, ee) => App.Current.Shutdown();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            App.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```