# How do I show a new window after having closed the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to do what is described in this post, display a log in window and when user successfully logs in, close it and open the main window of the application.

[If the user logs on successfully, then I want to show the main window, if not, I want to exit the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708992/if-the-user-logs-on-successfully-then-i-want-to-show-the-main-window-if-not-i)

but the provided answers (at the time of posting this question) do not work for me since my code to show the windows is running from the App.cs.

I know the reason, its because the first window that starts up is automatically set to be the MainWindow of the application and when I call Close() on it, it exits the application.  So the second window doesn't have a chance to open.

My question is how to overcome this? Or is this just not possible the way I described?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(){}

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginScreen f = new LoginScreen(); //becomes automatically set to application MainWindow
        var result = f.ShowDialog(); //View contains a call to Close()

        if (result == true) //at this point the LoginScreen is closed
        {
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow(); 
            App.Current.MainWindow = main;
            main.Show(); //no chance to show this, application exits
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If the user logs on successfully, then I want to show the main window, if not, I want to exit the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708992/if-the-user-logs-on-successfully-then-i-want-to-show-the-main-window-if-not-i)

Comment: Have you tried just moving the line MainWindow main = new MainWindow() to the first line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change application shutdown mode to `OnExplicitShutdown` and then call `Application.Shutdown(0)` whenever you want to. For example:

```
public App()
{
    App.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
}

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    if (MessageBox.Show("Continue?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        App.Current.Shutdown(0);
}
```

Here in the constructor I'm changing application shudown mode and calling Shutdown method if I need to.

**Caution:** When you change `ShutdownMode` make sure to call `Shutdown` method otherwise your application will be in memory even after main window closes. I've overrided `OnClosed` method in my MainWindow to do that:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
    App.Current.Shutdown(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**App.xaml** : (In this file set the start window with the login view)

```
StartupUri="LoginWindow.xaml"
```

**LoginWindow.xaml** : (A file with a login window view)

**LoginWindow.xaml.cs** : (Code Behind for the view. Place here the function assigned to login. )

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Access control. If correct, go ahead. Here you must create a condition check

    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    main.Show();

    this.Close();
}
```